# Dynamic index_name in elasticsearch-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rubygems

I am using [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) gem in my rails app. I want to set index name dynamically. In model i did this:

```
index_name {Account.current_account.subdomain}
```

Currently there is no support in the gem to do this. Here is the index_name method define in gem

naming.rb

```
# TODO: Dynamic names a la Tire -- `Article.index_name { "articles-#{Time.now.year}" }`
#
def index_name name=nil
    @index_name = name || @index_name || self.model_name.collection.gsub(/\//, '-')
end
```

How can i get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature [has been inplemented here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/pull/159) and released to rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

So you tried something like this and it didn't work? as it works for me?

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  index_name(Account.current_account.subdomain) # without the curly braces

  mapping do
     ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to pass the index name as a block that's why i used curly braces.

Comment: May I ask what is the gain of passing a block instead of a dynamic value? wont the block be executed as the dynamic value?

Comment: I am trying to create a dynamic index for each account which is logged in. I did this when i was using Tire gem and this functionality was supported in Tire but not in this gem as i mentioned in the question